# Is it possible to keep the command prompt always at the middle in the gnome terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, prompt

Is it possible to keep the command prompt always at the middle in the gnome terminal?

After entering each command the command prompt line is coming to the bottom, so is it possible to keep the command prompt line in the middle always in gnome terminal..?